# How can I get statements within functions to execute in a randomly chosen order?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, audio, random, switch-statement

I'm relatively new to Matlab, and I've been trying to solve my problem for ages but I'm just continuously arriving at a dead end.

I have a code which should, in theory, play 3 sounds in a random order (each order being different for each trial). Upon each sound playing the participant will be asked which sound they heard and then given feedback. I have all the code complete and working up until the random order part. I have created code that on each trial will randomly order 1,2 and 3.

`Order = [1, 2, 3];
 PhonemeOrder = randperm (numel(Order));`

I then have a function which plays the sound/asks the questions etc. within this I have attempted switch cases statements and if else statements depending on the number that PhonemeOrder produces but the order doesnt change even when phoneme order does. I believe my problem is however that PhonemeOrder comes out like [1,2,3] or [3,1,2] which is what i wanted. but Im not sure how to get my sounds to play in the order that it shows because I am using code like...

`if/ PhonemeOrder = 1;
      then do this...
 elseif phonemeorder = 2; 
     then do this...
 else 
    do this...`

Or I've tried code like

`switch cases 
    case 1 
       do this 
    case 2 
       do this 
    case 3 
      do this`

I'm guessing this is where i am going wrong, but i just dont know how to change it and make it work! I hope this makes sense? I just need it to play in the order that phonemeorder specifies, with the order changing on each trial.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

bexG,

I think you are on the right track.
The only thing you need is to use a "for-loop" to go through the array of PhonemeOrder.

```
for i=1:length(PhonemeOrder)
  switch PhonemeOrder(i)
    case 1 
      play the first song
    case 2 
      play the second song 
    case 3 
      play the thrid song
    end
end
```

I hope this will help.
Please let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Your switch/case does not have an end and PhonemeOrder[i] is not a valid Matlab syntax...you need PhonemeOrder(i)